# Segfault when calling glDrawElements

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, segmentation-fault

I have an OpenGL application I'm developing on macOS. I have a call to `glDrawElements` in my code that segfaults. I'm linking against the `OpenGL.framework` file and include `<OpenGL/gl.h>`. However, if I include `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` the program does not segfault, and it works as expected for more or less (I'm still getting invalid operation calls but the mesh draws to the screen). Is this an extension loading issue? I am not using GLEW or any extension loading library. I am creating a 2.1 version context.

[Here](https://github.com/jefftime/pizza/blob/master/render/glrender.cc#L339-L408) is where I setup the OpenGL data, and [here](https://github.com/jefftime/pizza/blob/master/render/glrender.cc#L153-L215) is where I do the actual drawing. I will also note that this is up and running on a Linux machine with no issues. It just seems to be macOS where I'm having the segfault.

Here is the stack trace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x206bb7, 0x00007fff92a330d0 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 112, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff92a330d0 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 112
    frame #1: 0x00007fff78853c86 GeForceGLDriver`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5651$$GeForceGLDriver + 187
    frame #2: 0x00007fff78855102 GeForceGLDriver`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5659$$GeForceGLDriver + 771
    frame #3: 0x00007fff789710fe GeForceGLDriver`___lldb_unnamed_symbol10497$$GeForceGLDriver + 393
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8227a15f GLEngine`glDrawElements_Exec + 271
    frame #5: 0x0000000100030fb4 mcomp`GLRender::DrawModel(this=0x00007fff5fbff7f8, model=0x0000000100770e20) + 5956 at glrender.cc:202
    frame #6: 0x0000000100003fa7 mcomp`Mcomp::Update(this=0x00007fff5fbff7b8) + 423 at mcomp.cc:27
    frame #7: 0x0000000100007941 mcomp`Engine::Run(this=0x00007fff5fbff798) + 65 at engine.cc:22
    frame #8: 0x00000001000026ea mcomp`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa00) + 378 at main.cc:21
    frame #9: 0x00007fff92826255 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: @MohitJain I updated the answer with the stack trace

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: @diametralpitch added the relevant code sections

Comment: You should be binding GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER while your VAO is bound. That way the VAO will remember its association with the index buffer. In case of GL_ARRAY_BUFFER there is no such requirement, as that association is captured by VAO when you call glVertexAttribPointer().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing a few mistakes here.

- You *must* call glVertexAttribPointer() when you have the buffer object bound from which the vertex attribute should pull its data. I suggest first setting up and configuring the vertex buffer (including vertex attributes), then proceeding to do the index buffer separately. You are currently somewhat mixing and matching them.
- You may need to call glEnableVertexAttribArray() after calling glVertexAttribPointer(), though I don't entirely remember if the standard requires this.
- The Vertex Array Object keeps track of the vertex attributes you set up. In turn, vertex attributes remember which buffer object they pull data from. As such you do not need to bind your buffer objects explicitly when drawing.
- You usually get segmentation faults upon calling glDrawElements() when either the buffer objects you set up are too small, you are trying to draw more indices than your index buffer has, or your stride is off. It can thus be an idea to ensure all lengths, sizes, etc make sense to you. It may also occur when your index buffer referes to an out-of-bounds value, though if I recall correctly this may be up to the implementation on how to handle this.

For reference, here is the order in which I usually set up VAO's:

1. create VAO
2. bind VAO
3. create buffer (vertex)
4. bind buffer
5. fill buffer with geometry data
6. set up relevant vertex attribute pointers
7. enable vertex attribute pointers
8. create buffer (index)
9. bind buffer
10. fill buffer with indices

This should set everything up. To draw, use the relevant shader program, bind the VAO and call glDrawElements()

Edit: can you outline why exactly you are creating a 2.x context, and not a 3.x or 4.x context? Drawing with buffers and VAO's is the modern OpenGL way of rendering. Why not match the context version against that level?

Comment: I am targeting a Linux box that has Intel HD Graphics 3000. It cannot make a 3.2 Core context, so I just arbitrarily chose OpenGL 2.1 and decided to load in the proper extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the info regarding the Vertex Array Object binding order. That seems to be my problem. I have reordered things around and am not getting a segfault anymore. Nothing is drawing, but I will eventually figure out why :) at least it's not crashing!

Comment: From some googling it appears it should be able to support OpenGL 3.0. If nothing is drawing, make sure that the locations of the vertex attributes match those of your shader(s). Since you use a pre-GL 4.0 context, you may need to ask OpenGL what index particular attributes have (not sure if you do so already)

Comment: Is there much difference between 2.1 and 3.0 besides not having to load some extensions?

Comment: Basically, in 2.x there used to be a "fixed-function pipeline". This meant you could use functions such as glBegin(), glEnd(), glVertex(), etc to draw primitives. These functions are all hopelessly inefficient, map terribly on to modern hardware, and were thus done away with from version 2.x to 3.x in favour of buffer objects. These could be set up using functions such as "glVertexPointer()" or "glNormalPointer()". The fixed function pipeline was removed entirely.

Comment: Version 3 to 4 basically did away with having special attributes such as normals or texture buffers, only using "generic" buffers and leaving it to shaders to decide what to do with them. As such the 3.x "gl(Vertex|Normal|Texture|Color)Pointer()" functions no longer exist in v4, basically forcing you to use the method you are currently using to draw. So kudos on going that route in favour of the at this point dreaded glBegin()/glEnd() combo.